# Ideal place to read and write metadata using NSPersistentDocument?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

In my NSPersistentDocument subclass, I need to save some metadata to my document when I save it and, of course, read it back when I open the document. I did get it working, but I'm not sure if it's the proper way to handle it.  (My testing reflects a new, unsaved document being saved and then opened again. New, unsaved documents do not have an NSPersistentStore assigned until after the first save.)

Here's my working code with comments related to my testing and thought process of how to handle this:

```
- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{

    // No persistent store available yet

    BOOL result = [super readFromURL:absoluteURL ofType:typeName error:outError];

    // Persistent store available, but metadata may be already altered by configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL: 
    // if I were set the data there instead of in writeToURL:

    if (result == YES)
    {
        // Read metadata
        NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:absoluteURL];
        NSString * uuid = [persistentStore metadata][DefaultLocationUUIDKey];
        self.defaultLocationUUID = uuid;
    }

    return result;
}



- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL ofType:(NSString *)typeName forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)saveOperation originalContentsURL:(NSURL *)absoluteOriginalContentsURL error:(NSError **)error
{

    // No persistent store available yet

    BOOL result = [super writeToURL:absoluteURL ofType:typeName forSaveOperation:saveOperation originalContentsURL:absoluteOriginalContentsURL error:error];

    // Persistent store available, but has already been saved by this point

    // Get mutable copy of existing metadata and update with new data
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:absoluteURL];
    NSMutableDictionary *metadata = [persistentStore.metadata mutableCopy];
    metadata[DefaultLocationUUIDKey] = self.defaultLocationUUID;

    // Use this method because it saves the metadata directly to the file without having to re-save the document, is this correct? It works.
    // Are their negative side effects to altering the metadata in this way while the file is open? I haven't tested all possibilities.
    NSError *metadataError = nil;
    [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator setMetadata:metadata forPersistentStoreOfType:typeName URL:absoluteURL error:&metadataError];

    return result;

}




// Called for both open and save, but not for new documents (which is fine, use initWithType:error:)
- (BOOL)configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)fileType modelConfiguration:(NSString *)configuration storeOptions:(NSDictionary *)storeOptions error:(NSError **)error
{

    // No persistent store available yet

    BOOL result = [super configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:url ofType:fileType modelConfiguration:configuration storeOptions:storeOptions error:error];

    // Persistent store available, but how to determine if opening existing or saving a new document?
    // Don't want to alter existing record unless saving a new document.

    return result;
}
```

The documentation seems a little sparse on how best to handle a lot of things when using NSPersistentDocument so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.